# Repeatedly strumming one string: name and technique

Tags: technique, terminology

Is there a name or word for the action of repeatedly and quickly strumming a single string on a guitar, ukulele, lute or other similar instrument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tremolo. Yes, it's also the name for a wangy bar that was coined erroneously by a certain Mr. Fender. Can be performed using a pick, or 2,3 or 4 fingers.